# Can't connect to an Access 2013 file in Visual Basic 2012 using code

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access, visual-studio-2012, ms-access-2013

It's just a simple Access 2013 file. I'm using this connection string:

```
Dim odbccn As New Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=access.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;")
```

Connecting to the same file using the data source explorer seems to work, and it even provides that same connection string. But doing it with code brings up this.

```
System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException (0x80131937): ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it. Didn't know there was a difference between OleDB and ODBC. Well, I'm an idiot.